# When I create a new virtual environment, it doesn't point to the latest OpenSSL

Tags: python, openssl

I have two pythons installed on my MacOS- One that came shipped with the system, another that I installed in virtual environment. I upgraded the OpenSSL version to "OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017".

I created a virtual environment for my project using wrapper `virtualenv myenv` command. The problem that I'm hitting that the python inside the virtual environment is still pointing to the old OpenSSL.

```
>>> print "OpenSSL info: %s" % (ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
OpenSSL info: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

whereas the system Python returns the newer version.

```
>>> print ("OpenSSL info: %s" % (ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION))
OpenSSL info: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

How can I point the python inside virtual environment to the latest OpenSSL?

Comment: So how did you install the other Python version? A 'virtual enviroment' could mean several completely different things.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I used `virtualenv my_venv --system-site-packages` to set up a virtual environment.

Comment: And what Python version is `virtualenv` itself installed in, the system Python or a different Python installation? Where do the `lib/python2.7/` links point to?

Comment: So the python interpreter to my project points to `MyProject/env/bin/python` . That `bin` directory has files like pip, python, python2, python2.7, wheel and so on. I believe `virtualenv ` was installed on system wide Python.